# Convert colorized point cloud to colored raster

Tags: geotiff-tiff, point-cloud

Most of the tools that that I have seen convert a point cloud to a DEM. I am more interested in a GeoTiff that looks like a satellite imagery rather than an elevation map. What tool do I use to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: lasgrid would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free and open source CloudCompare to generate perpendicular projection to xy or xz or yz planes. Select the point cloud which you would like to project in the DB Tree panel. From the menu select Tools/Projection/Rasterize or select the Rasterize icon [image].
In the displayed dialog set the target resolution (step), the active layer should be RGB, the direction should be "Z". Pressing the "Update grid" button you can see the result on the right.

[image]

If your satisfied with the result, press Raster button at the bottom and select "Export RGB colors" and press OK.

[image]

Finally select the target GeoTiff file.